# buttons in listview help?

Tags: android

I need to put button into list view to go to another view.

my button:     AddTime = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Add_Time);

i tryd to get it working using:

public class myclass extends ListActivity  implements OnClickListener {

and i have 
public void onClick(View arg0) {
    }

and i need it to go to another place i think using this 
 Intent intent = new Intent(this, myclass.class);
    startActivity(intent);

how to i get this all working in listview?

Answer (score 0):

use this

```
package example.buttonWithList;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class buttonWithList extends ListActivity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    String[] items={"azhar","j"};
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        setListAdapter(new bsAdapter(this));


    }
    public class bsAdapter extends BaseAdapter
    {
        Activity cntx;
        public bsAdapter(Activity context)
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
            this.cntx=context;

        }

        @Override
        public int getCount()
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return items.length;
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int position)
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return items[position];
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position)
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return items.length;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
        {
            View row=null;
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            /*if(convertView==null)
            {

            }*/
                LayoutInflater inflater=cntx.getLayoutInflater();
                row=inflater.inflate(R.layout.row, null);
                TextView tv=(TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.txtRow);
                Button btn=(Button)row.findViewById(R.id.btnRow);
                tv.setText(items[position]);
                btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        onListItemClick(this, this, position, null);
                    }
                    });


            return row;
        }

        protected void onListItemClick(OnClickListener onClickListener,
                OnClickListener onClickListener2, int position, Object object) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            //Toast.makeText(this, items[position], 3000);
            System.out.println(items[position]);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <TextView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="@string/hello" />
    <ListView android:id="@android:id/list" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"></ListView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: It would probably make sense to edit this post, in order to add the code pieces in the other answers you posted, and then delete the other answer posts.  This would be more in line with how StackOverflow is used.

Answer (score 0):

row.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <TextView android:text="@+id/TextView01" android:id="@+id/txtRow"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"></TextView>
    <Button android:id="@+id/btnRow" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="Click "></Button>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use a list view with strings. Make a buttons array and when you click on one, via onClick get the button in the array with the position parameter